# Connecting SAS Datasets with Power Query

Tags: excel, sas, powerquery

Is there a way to establish a link between Excel Power Query and a SAS DataSet stored on my local drive?

Answer (score 0):

You can try connecting to it with an ODBC driver (they have some [here](https://support.sas.com/software/products/odbc/)) using From ODBC.